# What's a word to describe someone who loves to solve puzzles and mysteries?

Tags: single-word-requests, literature

One of my friends loves puzzles-jigsaw, logic, pretty much anything. He is also addicted to reading murder mysteries and tries to figure out who killed the guy. Basically, he enjoys working things out with his own brain. 
What word can I use to describe him?

Comment: @Jason Bassford. Just one problem the accepted answer in the Link is very suspect. The answer has no refrence source and the word is not listed in 4 dictionaries I tried including O.E.D. & M.W. so that covers both sides of the pond.

Comment: @Brad The first Google hit I got when searching for the word gave me its definition at [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/enigmatologist.html). Also, questions are marked as duplicates of other questions. It's nice if that question has a good answer, but it's not necessary. If there isn't one, that's still the question that should be getting one.

Comment: @Jason Bassford OK agreed. I'll see if I can find a more universally accepted answer for the original. I doubt it but I'll have a look.

Comment: I think there might be a difference between *someone who solves puzzles* and *someone who **loves** to solve puzzles*. The second implies a certain amount of joy derived from the activity, whereas the first almost sounds like a job. Although debatable whether it's a word or not(it's not), for this situation I would suggest **Puzzleholic**

Comment: *Puzzle devotee*...

Comment: **Never** consult a thesaurus when writing your résumé, especially not our local elugameosaurus here! :)

Answer (score 0):

A Sleuth

A sleuth is a ‘keen investigator’, someone who loves to solve problems.

Sleuth is from Old Norse meaning ‘trail or track’. From 1905 it also came to mean ‘private detective’.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/blessing

You can also describe your friend as a ‘super-sleuth’ - someone who is great at ‘sleuthing’ - solving problems and finding answers.